# Run PHP code on local MacOS Jekyll site, port 4000

Tags: php, localhost, jekyll

I've build a Jekyll website on my localhost (MacOS Mavericks). The website is served at http://localhost:4000/website/ and everything regarding Jekyll is running just fine.

However, I now want to have a contact form in PHP that allows me to receive emails. I placed a contact.php file in the website/ folder and have the form POST to that file. On my remote web server, this is working perfectly. However, on the localhost, the PHP isn't parsed, and plain text is displayed on contact.php. However, PHP is parsed perfectly on localhost/contact.php.

> How do I get my localhost (Apache? PHP?) to process PHP files on my local Mac http://localhost:4000/ (without breaking my Jekyll website that listens on the same :4000 port)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the same port.  The port determines the application endpoint that will handle the request on the IP address. The Jekyll server (WEBrick library) uses port 4000 as a default.

The typical way to handle this problem, is to use a "web service" to add dynamic functionality.  For instance, the [jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/resources/) suggest using something like **FormKeep**, or **SimpleForm**.

What you're asking is to setup a "web service" yourself.  To do this it would need to be on another port or another IP address.  The "service" will simply act as an endpoint to accept and process your form post.  In this case you could setup a webserver using Apache/PHP on a different port than Jekyll -- such as the standard port 80 -- then write a PHP script (e.g., webform.php) that in combination with the static form is setup to respond and process your form.

**Note:** It is *possible* to configure both Jekyll and Apache to respond to requests on port 4000.  However, both applications (aka servers) can't be running at the same time.  The ip:port combination determines which application an internet request is sent to.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the post is old but this may help someone...

The answer by Mike Stewart is excellent and describes what needs to be done to accomplish the goal.

To add to that answer, here are the specifics of how I do this type of development on a Mac.

- Configure CORS in Apache
- Run the Jekyll site on default port 4000
- Run MAMP stack on default port 8888
- Code goes in MAMP's htdocs folder (htdocs/your_project)
- PHP resides in a separete "php" or other folder inside the "your_project" folder
- Jekyll watches the "your_project" folder and compiles to _site as normal

The CORS issues you'll experience can be resolved locally during development several ways. Here is a good resource for enabling CORS on Apache: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Once you have CORS configured you'll be able to make Ajax calls to the PHP on port 8888.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the PHP built-in web server alongside the Jekyll server. I opened a second Terminal window and navigated to the `_site` folder. The command is `php -S localhost:8000` (or whatever port you want to use that is not 4000).

Note that I'm using viewing localhost:8000 in the browser, but having the Jekyll server running simultaneously is nice because Jekyll keeps the build updated as I make changes to the source code (refresh required).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).